# Using jQuery selectors with Javascript functions throwing errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to change from using jQuery for everything and playing around with more native javascript. However, I keep getting problems when trying to use jQuery functions with native selectors and javascript functions with jQuery selectors.

Below is a simple example about my problem (all were run separately):

```
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var text2 = $("#text");

text.style.color = "blue"; //this works    
text.css("color", "blue"); //throws text.css is not a function error

text2.css("color", "blue"); //this works
text2.style.color = "blue"; //throws Cannot set property 'color' of undefined error
```

I thought that jQuery was just javascript and that you could use native functions and methods with jQuery selectors and vice versa. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In your code `text` does not jQuery object. And it does not have `css` function. Use JavaScripts methods in this case.

Non-jQuery objects has native functions only.

UPD: also jQuery object does not have `style` property. So you call `style.color` and it equal to try to get `color` of undefined.

Comment: Ah, ok, I can understand that. But why would my jquery 'text2' throw an error when I use the javascript function .style.color?

Comment: jQuery object does not ordinary JavaScript object and has own set of properties

Answer (score 0):

There is no any `.css()` in the javascript; and
there is no any `.style` properties in the Jquery.